# Plot the Fermi-Dirac Distribution in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code which I think should plot the fermi-dirac distribution function: f(E)=1/(e^(E−EF)/(kBT)+1)

where in this case Fermi Level EF is 9.5eV. My code seems to plot it, except somehow the temperature dependence seems backwards (it should produce straight lines at lower temperatures and get curvy as T goes up). Basically, what the plot at 500K looks like is what the plot for 0K should look like, and as the temp goes up they should resemble what 0K looks like on my plot. Where is the mistake? The code is:

```
k = 8.62 * (math.pow(10, -5))
#define Boltzman's constant K
x = 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5
#Energy levels in eV
y = (Acount/24), (Bcount/24), (Ccount/24), (Dcount/24), (Ecount/24),(Fcount/24),(Gcount/24),(Hcount/24),(Icount/24),(Jcount/24),(Kcount/24),(Lcount/24),(Mcount/24),(Ncount/24),(Ocount/24),(Pcount/24)
#probabilities, normalized from 0 to 1

f0 = []
f50 = []
f100  = []
f200 = []
f300 = []
f400 = []
f500 = []
Evals0 = []
Evals50 = []
Evals100 = []
Evals200 = []
Evals300 = []
Evals400 = []
Evals500 = []





#I broke the equation into two smaller stages to try and make it easier to catch errors


for i in range(0, 16):
    Evals0.append(np.exp(x[i]-9.5))
    Evals50.append(np.exp((x[i]-9.5)/(k*50)))
    Evals100.append(np.exp((x[i]-9.5)/(k*100)))
    Evals200.append(np.exp((x[i]-9.5)/(k*200)))
    Evals300.append(np.exp((x[i]-9.5)/(k*300)))
    Evals400.append(np.exp((x[i]-9.5)/(k*400)))
    Evals500.append(np.exp((x[i]-9.5)/(k*500)))


for i in range(0, 16):
    f0.append(1/(1+Evals0[i]))
    f50.append(1/(1+Evals50[i]))
    f100.append(1/(1+Evals100[i]))
    f200.append(1/(1+Evals200[i]))
    f300.append(1/(1+Evals300[i]))
    f400.append(1/(1+Evals400[i]))
    f500.append(1/(1+Evals500[i]))



p1 = plt.plot(f0, x, label='0k')
p2 = plt.plot(f100, x, label='100k')
p3 = plt.plot(f200, x, label='200k')
p4 = plt.plot(f300, x, label='300k')
p5 = plt.plot(f400, x, label='400k')
p6 = plt.plot(f500, x, label='500k')
p7 = plt.plot(y, x, label= 'homework')
p8 = plt.plot(f50, x, label='50k')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('F(E)')
plt.ylabel('ENERGY')
plt.title('fermi-dirac distribution   F(E) Vs  Energy')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't you want to plot your evaluations as a function of x?
plt.plot takes the x coordinate first if you're using positional parameters.

Comment: The axis for this can be swapped, I prefer it this way. Am I somehow multiplying by temperature rather than dividing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem with large numbers in the exponent.
Try to look [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29873/integration-of-the-fermi-distribution-using-python) in the edit of the first answer.

And you cannot calculate the function at zero temperature this way because you should divide by zero. In this way you have infinity in the exponent and Fermi-Dirac function is either equal to 1 if x[i]-9.5 < 0, either equal to 0 if x[i]-9.5>0.